# Deploying Laravel 5 application

Tags: laravel, hosting

I have a blog written in Laravel 5 framework.

What is the easiest & cheapest way to deploy it ?

I thought of DigitalOcean using Forge and Envoyer. But that costs around a total of $25/month, which is of course too costly for me. Also I don't want to move to a shared hosting (I tried setting it up on a GoDaddy hosting account, but unfortunately I couldn't make it work).

I'm new to Hosting and deployment etc.

Comment: How about digitalocean? Basic plan like $5 ?

Comment: if you speak Dutch or German I can recommend you great VPS for 10 euros a month, you can deploy for free with deployhq.com & using bitbucket.

Comment: @xdevnull Can I deploy it on DigitalOcean without Forge and Envoyer? Only DigitalOcean is fine , but combining Forge & Envoyer service makes it too costly

Comment: You can use forge without Envoyer, that should cut your costs by another 10$

Comment: @Arminius Thanks, but I'm from India. Also I'm using Github, not Bitbucket.

Comment: @Pascal any tutorial on how to do that? I'm quite new into this

Comment: There is a free tutorial on laracast: https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge

Comment: @byteseeker Sure you can. You know it's recommended to use Forge it makes your life easier. but still, you can use DigitalOcean without Forge..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have zero knowledge of hosting & linux - Dont do it by yourself!

I can recommend some managed Laravel hosting like https://www.fortrabbit.com/